# Django save model with anonymous user

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-authentication

I have a Django model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module)
```

In my views.py:

```
def my_view(request):  
    ...
    project = Project.objects.create(
                  user=request.user,
                  product=product_instance,
                  ...
              )
    project.save()
```

I want to be able to save user as an authenticated user OR an `AnonymousUser` (which I can update later). However, if I'm not logged in I get this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "<django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject object at 0x1b498d0>": "Project.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

I guess that Django won't save the `AnonymousUser` because it is not a User as defined in the `User` model. Do I need to add the anonymous user to the `User` model, or am I missing something?

Any assistance much appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `user` field is a `ForeignKey`. That means it must reference *some user*.

By definition, the `AnonymousUser` is *no user*: in Django, there is no `AnonymousUserA` and `AnonymousUserB`. They're all the same: `AnonymousUser`.

Conclusion: you can't put an `AnonymousUser` in a `User` `ForeignKey`.

---

The solution to your issue is pretty straightforward though: when the `User` is anonymous, just leave the field blank. To do that, you'll need to allow it:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank = True, null = True)
```

Comment: Ok, great. So if I do `user=request.user` on an `AnonymousUser` then the field will be blank and no exception raised?

Comment: An Exception will be raised because you provided inappropriate data to the field. Just do `if request.user.is_authenticated(): project.user = request.user`

Comment: Do I also have to add `null-True`, as the field cannot be `null`?

Comment: @DarwinTech `null = True` affects *how* a blank value is stored, not *whether it can be stored*. You can add it, but it won't change make a difference here.

Comment: ok, with `blank = True` I generate the error: `IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")`. I ran south against the change but it says nothing changed.

Comment: @DarwinTech Something *did* change. You might want to do the migration by hand then?

Comment: But surely if I do not include `null = True` I will not be able to leave the field blank form the db point of view?

Comment: @DarwinTech Yep, you're right, sorry I got confused somewhere, do add it. South should pick up the migration once you do! : )

Comment: @DarwinTech Glad we finally got there! : )

Answer (score 0):

You might approach it like this where,

```
user = None
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    user = request.user

project = Project.objects.create(
              user=user,
              product=product_instance,
              ...
          )
```

And following this use the "user" in your methods. When it is anonymous user, it will be none.

Dont forget to define the user in your Project model as

```
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, ...
```